# How to remove chrome extension from electron?

Tags: electron

> **UPDATE:** The issue seemed to resolve itself after I restarted my Mac.

I recently tried integrating a chrome extension to my electron project but it did not work as intended. At this point, I realized I could not remove the extension. I have tried the methods shown in the docs to no avail:

```
BrowserWindow.removeExtension('name')
BrowserWindow.removeDevToolsExtension('name')
```

My issue is exactly like the one mentioned [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/7619), except I am using a Mac, not a PC so %appdata% does not work for me. For context, this was the solution given in the aforementioned question.

> Open the %APPDATA%\Electron folder and delete the DevTools Extensions file and extensions directory (or just remove your extension).

I have deleted the extension however, it still throws an error.

> Reading /Users/user/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/caahalkghnhbabknipmconmbicpkcopl/0.0.0.2_0/manifest.json failed.
>   Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/caahalkghnhbabknipmconmbicpkcopl/0.0.0.2_0/manifest.json'

Answer (score 1):

Try re-installing electron, just go into your project directory and use
`npm remove electron` to delete the electron browser from your npm bundle.
Then reinstall electron using `npm i --save electron`.

It should completely remove the chromium browser and then rebuild it from scratch. Thereby removing the extension.

Comment: I did not try this because the issue resolved itself. However, it seems highly likely that this would work.

Comment: Awesome glad it ended up going well :)